# MongoDB Join/Aggregate Query Returning Silence in Console

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongojs

I have two collections in my MongoDB that I'd like to join with an aggregate query, but am having difficulty returning the resultant object(s) to the console.  It currently returns nothing, which, in itself, is strange.  Hoping you can help...

*Collection 1 is **scrapedData** & scrapes articles from the Chicago Tribune:*

```
{
"_id": ObjectId("123"),
"headline":"Cubs Javier Baez Wins Silver Slugger Award",
"link": "www.chicagotribune.com",
 }
```

*Collection 2 is called **comments** and includes comments posted to my site linked to each article found from the scrape:*

```
  {
  "_id": ObjectId("456"),
  "articleId":"123",
  "author": "John Chicago"
  "message": "Good for Javier!"
  }
  {
  "_id": ObjectId("789"),
  "articleId":"123",
  "author": "Jane Q."
  "message": "MVP! MVP!"  
  }
```

*My current attempt at pulling together a response from the database that joins article headline, and all comments related to it, is:*

```
 db.comments.aggregate([
          {$match : {articleId : JSON.stringify(123)}},
          {
            $lookup:
              {
                from: "scrapedData",
                localField: "articleId",
                foreignField: "_id",
                as: "commentsPosted"
              }
         }
       ]),function(err, response) {
        if(err) {
          console.log(err); 
        } else {
          console.log(response);
        }
      }});
```

Any pointers you can share will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Pulled this proposed solution from the mongoDB documentation and a few related posts on Stack Overflow.  Still coming up empty in the console...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [aggregate documentation](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html#aggregate) your callback function and overall JS is somewhat messed up, try this:

```
db.comments.aggregate([
{ $match: { articleId: JSON.stringify(123) } },
{ $lookup: {
  from: "scrapedData",
  localField: "articleId",
  foreignField: "_id",
  as: "commentsPosted"
}}], function(err, response) {
 if (err) {
    console.log(err);
 } else {
    console.log(response);
}});
```

Or better using `Promises`:

```
return db.comments.aggregate([
 { $match: { articleId: JSON.stringify(123)}},
 { $lookup: {
   from: "scrapedData",
   localField: "articleId",
   foreignField: "_id",
   as: "commentsPosted"
 }}])
 .exec()
 .then(function(response) {
    console.log(response)
 }).catch(function(e){
    console.log(e)
 })
```

Comment: Thanks, Akrion.  I put through your first suggestion and the code is now returning all comments posted related to the articleId.  It is, however, still not pulling anything from the scrapedData collection.  Wondering if I need to include a second 'match' query criteria.  Not sure though.  Do you have any thoughts as to why this isn't pulling from the scrapedData collection?  Thanks, again, for your help on this!

Comment: OK, I'm seeing the issue now.  Entirely unrelated.  Thanks for your help, Akrion!